# Spring Boot serving static .webm and .mp4 files with wrong content type

Tags: spring-mvc, video, spring-boot, content-type, static-content

I've got a problem with a Spring Boot application that should serve static .webm and .mp4 files. When I put the files in the `static` folder on the classpath, the application serves them with content type `application/octet-stream` instead of `video/webm`, which makes them not work with `<video>` tags. I've tried customizing the resource handler, but it doesn't seem to provide any methods for setting headers. Images and other files work fine.

Spring Boot output:

```
$ curl -s -D - localhost:8080/CmMs.webm -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Jul 2016 18:08:41 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 648708
Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2016 18:22:40 GMT
```

Output as it should look

```
$ curl -s -D - http://webm.land/media/CmMs.webm -o /dev/null
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.19
Date: Tue, 05 Jul 2016 18:23:21 GMT
Content-Type: video/webm
Content-Length: 648708
Last-Modified: Tue, 05 Jul 2016 17:42:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27617275/spring-mvc-boot-does-not-send-mime-type-for-certain-files-woff-etc

Comment: Yup, that did the trick. Guess I searched for the wrong keywords. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anton Novopashin's answer did the trick. This helped:

```
@Component
public class ServletCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

    @Override
    public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
        MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
        mappings.add("webm", "video/webm");
        mappings.add("mp4", "video/mp4");
        container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
    }
}
```